# Focus chrome window in linux when running using xvfb

Tags: xvfb, xdotool

I am using the following shell script for to get the focus on a specific chrome window:

```
#!/bin/sh

WIDId=`xdotool search "Test page"`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WIDId
sleep 2
xdotool windowactivate $WIDId
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+a
```

It works when running normally but fails when running chrome using xvfb.
In xvfb it is unable to find the windowID.
I need it to get working with xvfb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked even without using windowactivate because I opened just one window that needed focus.